# NSToolbarItem availability based on OS X version

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I have an application that will be available across multiple versions of OS X. What's the best way to make an `NSToolbarItem` only available to users in certain OS versions. When it is not available, it should be completely hidden, not just disabled.

**To simplify, how do I remove a toolbar item from this (below) menu programmatically?**

[image: Toolbar Customization]

**Edit:** I tried to override `toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:` in the delegate like so:

```
- (NSArray *)toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar {
    NSLog(@"Toolbar requesting allowed items.");
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array addObject:@"TPUpToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPDownToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPResetToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPSpeedToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPGroupToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPBackgroundToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarShowFontsItemIdentifier];
    if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) <= 1038) {
        NSLog(@"Below Lion, adding Fullscreen item.");
        [array addObject:@"TPFSToolbarItem"];
    }
    [array addObject:@"TPFlipHToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPFlipVToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarSpaceItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarSeparatorItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarShowColorsItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarPrintItemIdentifier];
    return array;
}
```

All the other toolbar items show in the correct order, however the Fullscreen item is last, and still there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a better idea to check for feature availability than OS X version. What features are you using that aren't available in other versions?

Comment: But really the important thing is to hide or show the `NSToolbarItem`.

Comment: Why do you need your own toolbar item for fullscreen? There's already a button for it.

Comment: I need the button to go away in Lion and stay in Snow Leopard and lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NSGod was almost there. While the rest of his code works, it appears IB is overriding my code and adding in the Fullscreen button anyway. I had to move the toolbar item out of the toolbar and then manually point the `NSToolbarDelegate` to it by adding this method: (`up`, `down`, etc. are `IBOutlet`s)

```
- (NSToolbarItem *)toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar itemForItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag {
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"TPUpToolbarItem"]) {
        return up;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"TPDownToolbarItem"]) {
        return down;
    }

    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"TPResetToolbarItem"]) {
        return reset;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:NSToolbarShowColorsItemIdentifier]) {
        return colors;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:NSToolbarShowFontsItemIdentifier]) {
        return fonts;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:NSToolbarPrintItemIdentifier]) {
        return print;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"TPSpeedToolbarItem"]) {
        return speed;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"TPBackgroundToolbarItem"]) {
        return background;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"TPGroupToolbarItem"]) {
        return group;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItemIdentifier]) {
        return flex;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:NSToolbarSpaceItemIdentifier]) {
        return space;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"TPFlipHToolbarItem"]) {
        return flipH;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"TPFlipVToolbarItem"]) {
        return flipV;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:NSToolbarSeparatorItemIdentifier]) {
        return sep;
    }
    if ([itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"TPFSToolbarItem"]) {
        return fsItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget `-toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers:` in addition to `-toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:`. Try something like the following:

```
enum {
    MDUndeterminedVersion    = 0,
    MDTiger                  = 0x1040,
    MDLeopard                = 0x1050,
    MDSnowLeopard            = 0x1060,
    MDLion                   = 0x1070,
    MDMountainLion           = 0x1080,
    MDMavericks              = 0x1090,
    MDUnknownVersion         = 0x1100 // ??
};

static SInt32 MDSystemVersion = MDUndeterminedVersion;

+ (void)initialize {
    if (MDSystemVersion == MDUndeterminedVersion) {
        SInt32 MDFullSystemVersion = 0;
        Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersion, &MDFullSystemVersion);
        MDSystemVersion = MDFullSystemVersion & 0xfffffff0;
    }
}

- (NSArray *)toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar {
    NSLog(@"Toolbar requesting allowed items.");
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array addObject:@"TPUpToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPDownToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPResetToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPSpeedToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPGroupToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPBackgroundToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarShowFontsItemIdentifier];
    if (MDSystemVersion < MDLion) {
        NSLog(@"Below Lion, adding Fullscreen item.");
        [array addObject:@"TPFSToolbarItem"];
    }
    [array addObject:@"TPFlipHToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPFlipVToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarSpaceItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarSeparatorItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarShowColorsItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarPrintItemIdentifier];
    return array;
}
```

--

```
- (NSArray *)toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar {
    NSLog(@"Toolbar requesting default items.");
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array addObject:@"TPUpToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPDownToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPResetToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPSpeedToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPGroupToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPBackgroundToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarShowFontsItemIdentifier];
    if (MDSystemVersion < MDLion) {
        NSLog(@"Below Lion, adding Fullscreen item.");
        [array addObject:@"TPFSToolbarItem"];
    }
    [array addObject:@"TPFlipHToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:@"TPFlipVToolbarItem"];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarFlexibleSpaceItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarSpaceItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarSeparatorItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarShowColorsItemIdentifier];
    [array addObject:NSToolbarPrintItemIdentifier];
    return array;
}
```

Note that if you have allows user customization set for the toolbar, you may need to delete the apps pref file to notice a change in toolbar setup.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gestalt](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Gestalt_Manager/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: @spudwaffle: Just use the NSToolbar methods to change which items appear.

Comment: Those remove the visible items, but not those in the customization menu. How do I remove those?

Comment: Just change the result of `toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:` based on the system version.